# Why when i installed TMG i became disconnect and connect from internal network to TMG and external

Tags: microsoft-ftmg-2010

When I install TMG server 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2, after some minutes I have request time out in ping of internet and ping of ip address of TMG server. And I became disconnected from TMG and after some minutes I connected to it.

These are the things I did for installing TMG:

1. Set ip address on 2 NIC the LAN NIC don't have gateway and have DC IP address as a DNS and WAN NIC have ip address and getway and DNS=4.2.2.4
2. I have ping of internet and internal network all of the time on TMG server
3. Install pre-requirment of TMG server
4. Add access role for connectivity of LAN and Local host by this action__ allow from internal and local host to internal and localhost on all protocol all user
5. Add access role or connectivity of Internet by this role action allow from internal and localhost to external all protocol all user
6. In system policy open access remote and ping and mmc from internal, localhost, external
7. Disable firewall and attacker on antivirus

I try this scenario on 3 servers but I have this problem on all of them. Please help me if you have any solution for that.

Comment: Did you get the answer ? because i have the same issue >>> please replay :)

Comment: Watch the fireawll logs within TMG, see what it says is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what exactly you're asking about, but I think you're saying that you become disconnected from a server while installing TMG and have to wait a bit before you can connect to it.

If you're saying this happens as part of the installation process (or anything that forces a re-start of the TMG services) then this is as expected; the TMG install adds quite a lot of its own filters and firewall hooks to the standard windows server network stack and altering those can very well cause a brief interruption of networking on the host server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is after install TMG server. And this happen is not usuall and i think i didnt some of confige.because this server in not stable !! and all of the things after set this config work correctly but after few minute communication is cut and from a client inside a internal network i didnt have ping of tmg server and internet and remote session became disconnect... and after few minute later connection became ok and i have ping of internet & tmg server ( indeed suddenly became disconnect and then connect ) also after restarting tmg server connection is connect